# Count For loop with number at start of each line

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, counter

I have been trying to figure how to count the number of loops and display this number at the beginning of the loop.

```
:Search
set location=%cd%
cls
echo.
Echo. Searching for .exe files in %location% and subfolders
echo.
set /a count=0
echo.___________________________________________
echo.Found:
echo.
FOR /r %%i in (*.exe) do (echo. %count%. %%~ni & set /a count+=1)
echo.___________________________________________
echo.
title Exe blocker %count% Files found
echo. Number of files found with .exe extention: %count%
echo.
echo.
```

The above code searches for `exe` files in a folder (and sub folders). I want the code to display:

```
1. Firstexefilename
2. Secondexefilename
```

But it displays

```
0. FirstexefileName
0. SecondexefileName
```

The final count variable works fine displaying 2.

Comment: Read http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html, use `(echo. !count!. %%~ni & set /a count+=1)`

Comment: Thanks Josefz! worked a charm!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet shows some chances of solution with delayed expansion: [enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (expand variables at execution time rather than at parse time) or *disabled* (expand variables at parse time rather than at execution time, this is the [default behaviour](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
:Search
set "location=%cd%"
cls
echo(
echo( Searching for .exe files in %location% and subfolders
echo(
set /a count=0
echo(___________________________________________
echo(Found:
echo(
FOR /r %%i in (*.exe) do (echo( !count!. %%~ni & set /a count+=1)
echo(___________________________________________
echo(
title Exe blocker %count% Files found
echo( Number of files found with .exe extention: %count%
echo(
echo(
ENDLOCAL

echo( Another approach using `findstr.exe` and delayed expansion disabled:
echo(
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ('
  dir /B /S *.exe^|findstr /N "^"
  ') do (echo( %%i. %%~nj & set /a "counter=%%i")
echo(___________________________________________
echo(
echo( Number of files found with .exe extention: %counter%
ENDLOCAL
```

Yet another approach corresponding to your original solution:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:Search
set "location=%cd%"
rem cls
echo(
echo( Searching for .exe files in %location% and subfolders
echo(
set /a count=0
echo(___________________________________________
echo(Found:
echo(
FOR /r %%i in (*.exe) do (
  set "_filename=%%~ni"
  call :usevariable
  set /a "count+=1"
)
echo(___________________________________________
echo(
title Exe blocker %count% Files found
echo( Number of files found with .exe extention: %count%
echo(
echo(
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:usevariable
echo( %count%. %_filename%
goto :eof
```